# Code to autotsort files creating temp file instead of folder

Tags: matlab

In the below code I am trying to sort files based on a string within the name. I've been piecing this together with google searches and community help (I'm very new at matlab). Right now I'm getting two odd errors. First, when I try and make a folder, it creates some file (highlighted filein picture that I can't open and the wav files that should have been moved to the folder disappear.

I'm also having an issue where the code renames the first two data files moved to "01" and "01 (1)" and I have no idea why.

[image]

```
DirIn = 'C:\Folder\Experiment' %set incoming directory

eval(['filelist=dir(''' DirIn '/*.wav'')']) %get file list


for i = 1:length(filelist);
    Filename = filelist(i).name
    name = strsplit(Filename, '_');
    newStr = extractBetween(name,7,8);

    if strcmp(newStr,'01')
        DirOut = fullfile(DirIn, '01');
        mkdir DirIn DirOut

        movefile(fullfile(filelist(i).folder, filelist(i).name), DirOut);
    end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
DirIn = 'C:\Folder\Experiment'; %set incoming directory

filelist=dir(fullfile(DirIn, '*.wav')); %get file list
DirOut = fullfile(DirIn, '01');

for i = 1:length(filelist);
    Filename = filelist(i).name
    newStr = Filename(7:8);

    if strcmp(newStr,'01')
        if ~exist(DirOut)
            mkdir(DirOut)
        end

        movefile(fullfile(filelist(i).folder, filelist(i).name), DirOut);
    end

end
```

Firstly, you don't need `eval` to get the file list. `eval` impact performance significantly. The below is what you should have done:

```
filelist=dir(fullfile(DirIn, '*.wav'));
```

You don't need `strsplit` or `extractBetween` since you only intend to extract a part of the string by indexing, i.e. the 7th and 8th characters, you may do this:

```
newStr = Filename(7:8);
```

To use variable as an input, you need to use `mkdir` as a function rather than console command:

```
mkdir(DirOut)
```

Lastly, a bit of optimisation. Since `DirOut` is constant, you can take it outside the loop. You may also want to check if `DirOut` has already been created to avoid the warning message and overhead in `mkdir`.

There is no issue with `movefile`.

Comment: This is great. Thanks. Works perfect. Do you recommend running through each possible two-digit combo (00-23) as if loops?

Comment: @brc If it is a one-time job, this is the simplest way I don't see why not. But if you would reuse the code or need to include it in your report/paper etc., you might want to do it in a smarter way.

Comment: @brc, you can make a vector `combo = 1:23;` and convert `newStr` to a number `newDouble = str2double(newStr)`, then `pass = newDouble == combo` and `if any(pass) .....`

Answer (score 1):

Couple things go wrong, first, it is not recommended to use `eval`. In this case you can just create a character array to pass to `dir` as follows:

```
filelist = dir([DirIn '/*.wav'])
```

Then, you have a `strplit` that appears to do nothing, since it looks like your files don't have `'_'` in them, so `name` will just return `Filename`. But that is not the issue, since you are using `extractBetween` on the `Filename`.

The following does not what you think it does,

```
mkdir DirIn DirOut
```

will create two directories named `DirIn` and `DirOut` in the current working directory of Matlab. To create the directories you want, use:

```
mkdir(DirOut)
```

Since the output directory did not exist before, I suspect Matlab moved the file to the input directory, and renamed it to `01`, if you manually add the extension `.wav` it should be one of the original files.